# MVC HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden (IIS 8.5 - Windows Server 2012 R2)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-4.5, http-status-code-403

I'm deploying an ASP .NET MVC application to IIS. It works well in development with IIS Express, but when deploying it to IIS 8.5 I'm getting the HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden error.

I'm using .Net Framework 4.5. Already tried some solutions which worked on other IIS versions (7.0, 7.5, 10) but they seem not work in this specific version (8.5) on Windows Server 2012 R2

Features .NET Extensibility 3.5, .NET Extesibility 4.5, ASP.NET 3.5, ASP.NET 4.5, ISAPI Extensions, and ISAPI Filters are installed.

» not working

install Microsoft hotfix kb980368 » http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368
» is not valid for IIS 8.5 version

Comment: What url you are using to load application in browser? Http 403.14 error description is "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory". So if you don't have url mapped to MVC route then you will get this error.